# Accessing private member variables inside public member function

Tags: c++, class, templates

In function `myfun` is there a way to access `rhs.var` without writing a public function which returns `var`? Also, as I understand, this happens because `rhs` could be a different type... Is this correct?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class foo
{
private:
    T var;

public:
    foo(T v) : var(v) {}

    template<class Type>
    void myfun(foo<Type>& rhs)
    {
        auto i = rhs.var; //BOOM
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int> a = 5;
    foo<double> b = 2.2;

    a.myfun(b);
}
```

Comment: You may use `template <typename U> friend class foo;` inside `foo`

Comment: @Dieter Lücking So simple... Never would have thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Suggested Solutions

You could either provide a public accessor to your private member variable:

```
template<class T>
class foo {
  T var;
public:
  foo(T v) : var(v) {}
  T getVar() const { return var; }
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  template<class Type>
  void myfun(foo<Type>& rhs) {
    auto i = rhs.getVar();
                 ^^^^^^^^
  }
};
```

Or as already Dieter mentioned in the comments you could make your template class a friend:

```
template<class T>
class foo {
  T var;
  template <class> friend class foo;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
public:
  foo(T v) : var(v) {}
  template<class Type>
  void myfun(foo<Type>& rhs) {
    auto i = rhs.var;
  }
};
```

### Overview

The reason why the template member function `myfun` is not granted access to private member variable `var` of class template foo is that the compiler interprets `class foo<Type>` and `class foo<T>` as completely different class types, even though they would originate from the same template class definition. Thus, as being different class types the one cannot access the private members of the other.

Comment: You can even remove the `U`, `template <typename> friend class foo;`

Answer (score 1):

you can define the second type as fried like:

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
private:
    T var;

public:
    foo(T v) : var(v) {}

    template<class Type>
    void myfun(foo<Type>& rhs)
    {
        auto i = rhs.var; //BOOM
    }

    template<class Type> 
      friend class foo;
};
```

[live example](http://cpp.sh/4kn4)